# UICollectionView with self-sizing cells resizes cells during insert/remove animation

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a simple UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout that uses autolayout to allow for self-sizing cells. Things work great in a static layout, but when I insert or remove cells, the cells resize to the estimated size:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
} completion:nil];
```

Beyond setting the estimated size, like this:

```
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(88.0, 88.0);
```

I'm not doing anything fancy in the collection view. Everything is set up using storyboards.

How can I avoid this resizing? I'm only targeting iOS 8.0 and up so it should be supported.

[image: example of the problem]

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I'm having the exact same problem!

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'll ask again on the Apple forums. On iOS 9 it just crashes outright so I must be missing something.

Comment: I noticed this after raising a similar issue of my own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045566/uicollectionview-cells-resizing-when-deleting-items-with-estimateditemsize. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @AshleyMills nope, never

Comment: Self-sizing for collection views is turning out to be a nightmare.

Comment: Still seeing the same problem in iOS 10 beta 2

Comment: Getting the same issue here too. The fact it's still in iOS 10 when it came out in iOS 8 is a nightmare!

Comment: I also stumbled over this. And it seems that there is no solution to find anywhere. I will now calculate the sizes myself with systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(targetSize: CGSize) on a static dummy cell.

Comment: Try running `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` after the insert or within the completion block. If that doesn't work then I would just manually calculate the size for each cell in `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` ... the automatic resizing can definitely get funky at times

Comment: @AdelaChang `invalidateLayout` sadly doesn't help. Sad part is that they even "improved" self-sizing with `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`, presented at this year's WWDC. Meh.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this, and it took me a while to figure out that the size it was reverting to was the estimated size.

I think I figured out a workaround:

- Keep one instance of your self-sizing cell class around
- Implement `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, and configure that cell instance with data for that index path, then ask it for its preferred size (`systemLayoutFittingSize`).
- Cache this information in a dictionary for performance.

See example project [here](https://github.com/tomhamming/collection_view_auto_size_reorder).

Comment: Self-Sizing cells are just broken and don't work beyond WWDC demo cases

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `estimatedItemSize` property to some appropriate size.
2. In your custom `UICollectionView` class override below method and cache layoutAttributes's size given by super.

   ```
   -(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*)preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
   {
       UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * superAttr = [super preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:layoutAttributes];
      //Cache size which is returned by super (superAttr.frame.size) since super calculates the correct size for auto size cells.
       return superAttr;
   }
   ```

3.In sizeForItemAtIndexPath return cached size if available else estimated size.

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //return cached size if available else the estimated size
}
```

Comment: Saved my day! But I've made custom flow layout to cache attrs from `shouldInvalidateLayout(forPreferredLayoutAttributes`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid cell resize use InvalidationContext

```
    let context = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext()
    context.invalidateFlowLayoutAttributes = false
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An straightfoward solution is to implement the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layoutcollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      // calculate string size here
}
```

And after inserting or deleting cells make sure you invalidate layout so that delegate method is called again

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ 
    // insert/delete items here
}) { (success: Bool) in
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```